# How to skip and disregard a row in a loop that can't be read by a line of code or that provides error?

Tags: r, loops, try-catch

```
structure(list(`total primary - yes RS` = c(0L, 138L, 101L, 86L, 
118L), `total primary - no RS` = c(0L, 29L, 39L, 35L, 38L), `total secondary- yes rs` = c(0L, 
6L, 15L, 3L, 15L), `total secondary- no rs` = c(0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 
2L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I had previously asked for a line of code that could run a chisquare for each of four rows included

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750999/with-r-i-would-like-to-loop-through-each-row-and-create-corresponding-chisquare/66751018#66751018
```

Though the script worked it only worked because the four rows were able to run through the script.

```
 library(broom)
 library(dplyr)
 apply(df, 1, function(x) tidy(chisq.test(matrix(x, ncol = 2)))) %>%
 bind_rows
```

I now have a line that has zero and when i run the same script i get

```
 Error in stats::chisq.test(x, y, ...) : 
 at least one entry of 'x' must be positive
```

I tried to do something using tryCatch(), this way

```
 tryCatch(apply(df, 1, function(x) tidy(chisq.test(matrix(x, ncol = 2))))) %>%
 bind_rows
```

but it did not work. Ultimately the dataset has a bunch of rows like this I would like a scenario where the script recognizes that it isn't only in row 1, but in multiple rows like 5,23,67 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am following your code/data exactly, but what if you move your tryCatch statement inside the apply statement like so: `apply(df, 2, function(x) tryCatch(tidy(chisq.test(matrix(x, ncol = 2))))) %>% bind_rows`? Does that help at all?